# Google API Auth without knowing url

Tags: wordpress, google-api

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin which posts events to a users google calender.

I want to be able to authenticate a Google user from the plugins` admin screen but as I don't know the URL of the WordPress site, I can not add this as a redirect URl in the developer console.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in wordpress to retrieve the sites url:

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

> The **site_url** template tag retrieves the site url for the current site (where the WordPress core files reside) with the appropriate protocol, 'https' if is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise.

[Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

Comment: Not quite what I am after, this is regarding googes authentication procedure,